# Linking ipython widget button and slider values

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to figure out how to link the value of a counter controlled by button widgets to the value of a slider widget.

The goal here is use ipython widgets to create a simple "vcr-like" interface with three widgets: an `IntSlider` and two `Button`s that increment a counter and decrement a counter.  This is what I've got:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from functools import partial
from IPython.display import display
import traitlets

class Counter:
   def __init__(self, initial=0):
      self.value = initial

   def increment(self, amount=1):
      self.value += amount
      return self.value

def button_plus(counter, w):
    counter.increment(+1)  

def button_minus(counter, w):
    counter.increment(-1) 

counter = Counter()
# 1 step forward button
wplus = widgets.Button(description='>')
wplus.on_click(partial(button_plus, counter))
# 1 step backward button
wminus = widgets.Button(description='<')
wminus.on_click(partial(button_minus, counter))
# integer slider
wpick = widgets.IntSlider(value=0,min=0,max=10,step=1,description="time step")

display(wminus, wpick, wplus)

print(counter.value)
print(wpick.value)
```

and here's a screen grab where I've moved the IntSlider to 1 and clicked twice on the increment button:
[image]

I'd obviously like there to be a single integer value being controlled by and be in sync with all 3 widgets.

I read about [widget linking](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/examples/Widget%20Events.ipynb) but I don't see how to do this since my button widgets don't have a value -- the counter object has the value I want to link.

This doesn't work:

```
l = traitlets.link((counter, 'value'), (wpick, 'value'))
```

because `counter` is not `HasTraits`.

How can I get `counter.value` to be linked to `wpick.value` so that clicking on one of the buttons will adjust the int on the slider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/examples/Custom%20Widget%20-%20Hello%20World.ipynb) guide, you need the `Counter` class to inheret from the `DOMWidget` class like this:

```
from traitlets import CInt, link
class Counter(widgets.DOMWidget):
    value = CInt(0, sync=True)
```

You can then define your `counter` widget and button callback methods:

```
counter = Counter()
def button_plus(name):
    counter.value += 1 if counter.value < 10 else 0
def button_minus(name):
    counter.value -= 1 if counter.value > 0 else 0
```

link the `slider` and `counter` widgets:

```
link((wpick, 'value'), (counter, 'value'))
```

and register the events on the buttons:

```
wplus.on_click(button_plus)
wminus.on_click(button_minus)
```

Clicking the buttons will now in/decrease the value of the counter.

Comment: what does `name` refer to in your answer?  Do you also have different definitions of `wplus` and `wminus`?

Comment: @RichSignell - `name` is the name of the widget calling the callback method. Its not used but atleast one input in the method definition is needed as the `on_click` sends `name`. I used the same definitions for `wplus` and `wminus`. Why? is it not working for you?

Comment: you are right.   It works fine once I got rid of my coding errors: https://gist.github.com/rsignell-usgs/0067e0db0cfd8c3ed4bc

Comment: @RichSignell - Just a tip: In your gist you haven't defined the class method `increment` but sometimes it is still defined in the namespace from a previous run. To avoid this i always start my ipynb's with `%reset -f%`.