# Two ipython widgets for one variable

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am trying to make a interactive function where I can control the input with 2 widgets for the same variable. I Trying this because I want to have the option to slider the values (for a quick view) and also pick one specific (typing one value). I tried this linking the widgets with the `ipywidget.jslink`. I guessed once the widgets where linked I could input the values in any of them to pass to the variable. However, it is not what happens: below, only the values I set in the Slider updates the function (in other words, typing a value in the widget doesn't update the output). Why doesn't `jslink` work? In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634142/linking-ipython-widget-button-and-slider-values) I found that substituting `ipw.jslink` for `traitlets.link`works fine.

```
import ipywidgets as ipw    
from IPython.display import display
def f(x):
    return x**2
a=ipw.IntSlider(min=-10,max=20,step=1,value=10)
b=ipw.IntText(min=-10,max=20,step=1,value=10)
ipw.jslink((a,'value'),(b,'value'))
wid=ipw.interactive(f, x=a)
display(wid,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the Python objects not updating on the backend, it is probably because you are using `jslink` instead of `link` [[ref]](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Events.html#The-difference-between-linking-in-the-kernel-and-linking-in-the-client). Otherwise, I think this is an old issue with a previous version. I recreated with captured output and both the slider and Text call the function `f(x)`:

```
from IPython.display import display

output = ipw.Output()

@output.capture()
def f(x):
    print(x**2)
    return x**2

a=ipw.IntSlider(min=-10,max=20,step=1,value=10)
b=ipw.IntText(min=-10,max=20,step=1,value=10)

ipw.jslink((a,'value'),(b,'value'))

wid=ipw.interactive(f, x=a)
display(wid,b)
display(output)
```